# How can I override a security-constraint within a webapp deployed to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

I'm in a bit of a pickle, but a reasonable solution to this could potentially help quite a few people (even thousands?).

I wanted to deploy the latest version of Jenkins (1.599 at time of writing) to a Tomcat container (7.0.39) and then force all traffic to use SSL.

I set the connectors in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml to what they needed to be. I then added the following to the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml ...

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Jenkins</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Sadly, however, this wouldn't work as it's being overwritten by the web.xml within the Jenkins war.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>other</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <!-- no security constraint --> 
</security-constraint>
```

As I understand it, there is no way to allow me to force settings from the Tomcat web.xml. I will not manually edit my WAR every time a new version comes out, this is not an option.

So, the question is, what's the best way of either changing the server OR client-side web.xml so that the default settings still exist, but we can optionally force a transport-guarantee of CONFIDENTIAL.

Any ideas are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help, but I had the opposite problem. Corporate policy is to not allow PUT, DELETE or OPTIONS, so they have a section like this in the tomcat conf/web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>
       restricted methods
     </web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
     <http-method> PUT </http-method>
     <http-method> DELETE </http-method>
     <http-method> OPTIONS </http-method>
     <http-method> TRACE </http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

I found I could override this in the application web.xml for a subdirectory

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>REST Endpoints</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

But not for the context root (the following did not allow OPTIONS to work):

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>REST Endpoints</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

The implication for you is that you may be able to require SSL for a subdirectory without any problems. Not sure if this is sufficient for your jenkins requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the following language from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html:

> When the same url-pattern and http-method occur in multiple security
>   constraints, the constraints on the pattern and method are defined by
>   combining the individual constraints, which could result in
>   unintentional denial of access.

This suggests that the constraints that you specified will be combined, which means that what you are trying should work. Are you sure that SSL is configured properly on the server? Does editing the web.xml in the application actually fix the issue? This section from the same article seems to suggest that if SSL is not properly configured, it may fall back to http:

> To guarantee that data is transported over a secure connection, ensure
>   that SSL support is configured for your server. SSL support is already
>   configured for the GlassFish Server.